# Как удалить ключи из одного массива по ключам другого массива?

Tags: php

Есть 2 массива, как из 1-го:

```
array(2) { 
  [2582866]=> int(1),
  [23946139]=> int(3) 
}
```

удалить элементы, ключи которых также встречаются во втором массиве?

```
array(20) { 
  [2582866]=> int(0),
  [5617257]=> int(0), 
  [11734485]=> int(0),
  [18836027]=> int(0),
  ...
}
```

Пробовал  $final = array_diff($final,$banlist); но он только для value а не для ключей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$final = array_diff_key($final,$banlist);
```